# How is it possible to make the map on the geoserver (map from osm) with streets name, etc

Tags: openstreetmap, geoserver

Maybe there are files with data somewhere or how I can do it by myself?
[What I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXUuz.png)

Comment: Related question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243734/how-to-add-names-of-streets

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to add a text symbolizer. See the documentation:

- http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/textsymbolizer.html
- http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html
- http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/index.html

Comment: Thanks (: But one more question - if my workspace is consists of the 4 layers, so do I need to create only one sld file for the all layers, or I should create more different layers and sdl files for all of them?

Comment: One style per layer